# Visual Studio vs version controlling

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, version-control

I have ASP.NET project, which is under Git.
I want to make some small change in aspx file and of course it generates connected change in aspx.Designer.cs file.
However, I want a patch commited to be relevant to change I've made - this is so that I can (for example) do code review without need to skip all automated changes.

Therefore I want to add *.Designer.cs files to .gitignore and regenerate them when updating local workspace (automatically, not file by file).
I've been searching for some command line to compile aspx files but without success.

Could you possibly know some solution to my problem?

For now my environment is Windows+Cygwin.

Comment: You do not want to git to ignore Designer.cs. In a nutshell, you still want to check in Designer.cs file although you only change aspx file. Otherwise, aspx file will be out of sync with designer file.

Comment: I've never seen an option in the tooling to re-generate the designer files.  Honestly, this sounds like an invented problem.  Is there really a need to engineer a more complex solution just to commit fewer files?  In the long run it's going to be a lot easier to support a system which makes use of the tooling rather than one which fights the tooling.

Comment: I see your point but for me designer files are similar to dlls - they are output of IDE and you cannot (shouldn't) edit them manually. What is the purpose of storing them in a repository? I think that the only reason is lack of tool to compile whole solution together with generating designer files. I can agree that you could live with these files in a repository but I would really prefer to keep only source files in repository and do whole compiling independently.

Comment: The majority of developers would disagree with your view on designer files.  Source code is source code, whether it's generated by hand or by a tool.